# PHP version: 5.1.6: Cannot write to file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I am using version 5.1.6 and am observing a strange issue. I cannot create and write to a file from the script whereas if I explicitly create a file and then run the script it writes data.

Am I missing something obvious in here?

The test code I am trying is:

```
$message = "Test";
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
if (file_exists($myFile)) {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
  fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
} else {
  chmod("/path/to/dir/*", 0755); //updated code
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')  or die("Cannot open file \"$myFile\"...\n");
  fwrite($fh, $message) ;
}
fclose($fh);
```

CONCLUSION:
Thanks for the responses everybody. It is a permission issue. I changed the directory path and it works :)

Comment: permissions issue ? use <a href="http://php.net/manual/fr/function.chmod.php">chmod</a>

Comment: It's a file and directory permission issue and not related to this ancient PHP version that should be updated!

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ : Tried to change the permissions but still facing the same issue (edited code above)

Comment: @iDev There is nothing wrong with your code, far as I can tell. You have, as the others have said, a "path" issue and/or "permissions". And why are you using this `chmod("/path/to/dir/*", 0755);` with a star? You're trying to chmod "everything"?

Comment: @iDev Just for testing purposes, try your code without `chmod("/path/to/dir/*", 0755);`

Comment: @Fred - I tried without changing the permissions and it worked!

Comment: @iDev Great, so shall I mark your question as being answered by entering it as an answer, or do you require further help?

Comment: @iDev You're welcome. I submitted my answer where you can put a checkmark underneath the arrows. I'm glad it worked out, cheers. (*Peace*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Only the line where chmod resides, is not required.

Commented out `chmod("/path/to/dir/*", 0755);` this will chmod all files within the set folder.

Consult the PHP manual on [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) at 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

```
$message = "Test";
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
if (file_exists($myFile)) {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
  fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
} else {

//chmod("/path/to/dir/*", 0755);
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')  or die("Cannot open file \"$myFile\"...\n");
  fwrite($fh, $message) ;
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by changing the owner of the folder to the **apache** user. This should give your php script needed permissions for making files and writing to the files in that folder.
I guess you won't be able to chown the folder from php script, only through server access (ssh or ftp). At least, that was the path I had to go.